# Testing membership for perfect square number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Is it sufficient to test that if a positive integer $n$ ends in $0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 9$, and that $n \equiv 0, 1 \bmod 4$ then $n$ is a perfect square?

The numbers $0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 9$ I got from the quadratic residues mod 10. These proved that all perfect squares have these numbers as their final digit in decimal notation.

Are there better methods to test whether a number $n$ is a perfect square?

For example, the number $3190491$ ends in $1$, and $3190491 \equiv 3 \bmod 4$, therefore it is not a perfect square. But the number $100 \equiv 0 \bmod 4$ and ends in $0$.

Comment: Do you mean to ask if it's *necessary*?  $20$ ends in $0$, and $20\equiv0\bmod4$, but $20 $ is not a perfect square

Comment: How would I make this sufficient?

Comment: $5$ is the smallest counterexample.

Comment: Then, for numbers greater than 2 digits can we consider this as a test for *exclusion* from the set of perfect squares?

Comment: If it's congruent to $0\bmod n^2$ for any square $n^2$ less than itself,  it's not square free ...

Answer (score 1):

The tests you have give:
$0, 1, 4, 5, 9, 16, 20, 21, 24, 25, 29, 36, 40, ... 20n, 20n+1, 20n+4, 20n+5, 20n+9, 20n+16$.  This obviously is too many: squares get rarer as you go up, these things don't.  In fact, there is no finite combination of residue checks that you can perform to affirm that a number is a perfect square, for this same reason: no matter how many residue checks you do, you can replace them with a single very large residue check, and the things that pass that residue check do not get rarer as the numbers get larger.

Comment: Is the math up there going bonkers for anyone else?

Comment: So, then, a follow up question is how many residue checks does one have to do for an integer $n$? Is there a hidden inequality in this answer?

Comment: let's see.  5 is excluded by residue mod 3 (can only be 0 or 1); so is 20; 21, uh... it's allowed to be 1 mod 2, 0 mod 3, 1 mod 4, 1 mod 5, 3 mod 6, 0 mod 7... but it's not allowed to be 5 mod 8.  that's a long way up, and there are easier ways.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A139401 OEIS to the rescue.  that's a pretty small number of entries, if I get bored tomorrow I might send them an extension